# ObjectInputStream wont load Array of Objects after second Run - Java

Tags: java, arrays

I've been trying to apply the followed code in a wider scheme. Right now I am just trying to understand the concept of ObjectInput/outputStreams and how they handle Array of objects.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class WritFile {
    private FileInputStream output;
    private ObjectInputStream outPut;
    private FileOutputStream input;
    private ObjectOutputStream inPut;
    private Haha obj[];

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        WritFile obj = new WritFile();
        obj.Shazam("src\\Aloha.txt");
    }

    public void Shazam(String path) {
        obj = new Haha[30];
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            obj[i] = new Haha();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            obj[i].q1 = " Name" + i;
            obj[i].x = i;
        }
        int No = 5;
        saveToFile(obj, path);
        int counter = 0;
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < ReadFromFile(path).length; i++) {
                if (ReadFromFile(path)[i].q1 != null) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
                if (ReadFromFile(path)[i] != null) {
                    obj[No++].q1 = ReadFromFile(path)[i].q1;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.printf("error1 : %s", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < ReadFromFile(path).length; i++) {
                if (ReadFromFile(path)[i] != null) {
                    System.out.println(ReadFromFile(path)[i].q1);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.printf("error2 : %s", e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.printf("%s %n", "*******************");
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(obj[i].q1);
        }
        saveToFile(obj, path);
    }

    public void saveToFile(Haha arr[], String path) {
        try {
            input = new FileOutputStream(path, true);
            inPut = new ObjectOutputStream(input);
            inPut.writeObject(arr);
            inPut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.printf("Crashd : %s", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public Haha[] ReadFromFile(String path) throws Exception {
        output = new FileInputStream(path);
        outPut = new ObjectInputStream(output);
        return ((Haha[]) outPut.readObject());
    }
}
```

My goal with this code is to store some data into an array of objects (OBJ) then save that array to a file using the function I created. Then read the data from the file and store it in the First empty index in the same array  and so on.
For some reason it doesn't seem to write the data to the file after the first run :( !

Help!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SerializableArray implements Serializable, AutoCloseable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static File ardatei;
transient Integer[] currentarray;


private int cntoverwrite; 
FileInputStream fi;
BufferedReader br;
ObjectInputStream in;
int cnt; 


public SerializableArray(Integer[] integers, String filename) throws IOException {
    ardatei = new File(filename);
    currentarray = integers;

    if (!ardatei.exists())

    {




        try {
            ardatei.createNewFile();
             System.out.println("your file is created....");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("could not create File");
            System.exit(-1); 
        }
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ardatei);
                ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                o.writeObject(integers);


                o.flush(); 
                o.close(); 

    } else if (ardatei.exists() || zustand > 0) {

        FileOutputStream fos =
                new FileOutputStream(ardatei);
                ObjectOutputStream o =
                new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                o.writeObject(integers);
                 o.writeObject("\n " + "your file was overwrite.");

                 System.out.println("your file exists and become overwritten"); 
                o.flush(); 
                o.close(); 

    }

}
```

method to read data from given file

```
    public SerializableArray(String filename) {
    File f = new File (filename); 
    fi = null; 
    br= null; 
    in = null; 
    if (f.exists()){
        try {
            try {
                fi = new FileInputStream(filename);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Loading file failed...");
            }
             in = new ObjectInputStream(fi);
            System.out.println("Read data....");  
            //Cast to integer because readObject returns a object
            currentarray  =(Integer[]) in.readObject();


        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("could not read file....); 
        } 

    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException ("this file doesnt exist yet"); 
    }
    }
```

that code works in my case ^^

Comment: I have not tride this code but I can see that it only writes data and does not read,  I need to first write data into the file from the array given and then read the data and add it into the first empty index of the same array,  my code only failes in the second run after it successfully reads the data to the array it does not seem to be able to write it again to the file, I hope what I just wrote makes sense thx!